# How can I filter a table in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I am moving my Excel table on my current projects to OneNote due to the shared access capabilities. I have migrated all of my data from Excel to OneNote. The only problem with OneNote is that there is no facility for me to filter tables according depending on the data highlighted in a cell.

Is there any way I can filter a table in OneNote? Or should I just embed that part of the table as a Excel sheet? (However that brings up the problems with contention I was trying to avoid.)

Answer (score 1):

### OneNote doesn't support table filtering

OneNote is a tool focus on note-taking. It does not support advanced data manipulation features such as most of what you find in Excel, including table filtering. If you require this feature then you should use Excel.

#### But Office 365 Excel supports simultaneous editors!

If you and all of the other potential editors of your Excel workbook have Office 365 accounts you can  edit the workbook simultaneously. Simply save the Excel workbook to either OneDrive or a SharePoint library and save a link to it in your OneNote notebook. Then anyone with an Office 365 account will be able to open and edit it at the same time other users are in the workbook.

**More information**

- [Collaborate on Excel workbooks at the same time with co-authoring](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-excel-workbooks-at-the-same-time-with-co-authoring-7152aa8b-b791-414c-a3bb-3024e46fb104?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#ID0EAABAAA=Windows)
- [Work together on Office documents in OneDrive](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/work-together-on-office-documents-in-onedrive-ea3807bc-2b73-406f-a8c9-a493de18258b)